# jQuery iframe hide/show

Tags: jquery, iframe, hide, show

Well im coding a site, and now stuck at the jQuery part, which aint my strongest thing.
The site contains a top-menu nav-bar:

```
<a href="aboutus.html" target="iframe"><img class="tab1" src="#.png"></a>
<a href="menu.html" target="iframe"><img class="tab2" src="#.png"></a>
<a href="gallery.html" target="iframe"><img class="tab3" src="#.png"></a>
<a href="shop.html" target="iframe"><img class="tab5" src="#.png"></a>
<a href="links.html" target="iframe"><img class="tab6" src="#.png"></a>
<a href="contact.html" target="iframe"><img class="tab7" src="#.png"></a>
</div>
```

And a iframe in the middle of the page, which loads the new html on nav click.
When the index page loads,  the iframe should not be seen before nav click.
So ive got: iframe {display:none;} in css.

So, i need help with jQuery coding to show the iframe on nav click.
Also with an effect to make the iframe hide again.

All the best.

Comment: Nothing yet really - the problem is i dont know how to approach it. I guess its just a simple show/hide onclick?, because the href loads the html content?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the `<iframe>` has an `id` of `contentIframe` you could do the following:

Show the `<iframe>`:

```
$("#contentIframe").show();
```

Hide the `<iframe>`:

```
$("#contentIframe").hide();
```

Comment: You can download it from http://jquery.com and add a reference to the .js file in your .html page using a <script src="<path to jquery.js>"></script> block.

Comment: ah right - but i was too fast - i mean should this just be in the head?

Comment: Adding a script block to the head section is the generally accepted way to do it. However, you can add a script block almost anywhere in the .html file.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you try to use a div and use the .load() method it will be better than the use of an iframe

```
$("a").click(function(){
$("#mydiv").load($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: What if the iframe has an ID as Shardul says? Shouldnt I be able to make that ID work instead of a div wrapper?

Comment: <iframe style="visibility:hidden;" onload="this.style.visibility = 'visible';" id="myiframe" src="" > </iframe>

$("a").click(function(){
$("#myiframe").attr("src",$(this).attr("href"));
});
voila

Answer (score -2):

The [jQuery toggle method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) would be helpful.