# jquery to hide zen desk chat in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

i have a code that should hide any div's that could leak traffic (like phone, live chat etc.)

it works for hiding divs but I don't know how to use it to hide the zendesk chat widget which seems to load in an iframe

here is the code

```
<!— SCRIPT --> 

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://event.website.com/javascripts/postmessage.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'> 
window.dp_network_url = 'event.website.com';
window.dp_campaign_unique = '884f13c4f';
window.dp_cookie_result = function(data){
if(data && data.indexOf(":click:")) { 
jQuery(".CONTAINER_IDENTIFIER").hide(); 
} else { 
jQuery(".CONTAINER_IDENTIFIER").show(); 
} 
} 
xtd_receive_cookie(); 
</script> 
<!— EoF SCRIPT →
```

thank you

Comment: I think people should know which website is shown, and what's the parent DIV of it. If it's possible then just hide the iframe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery iframe hide/show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774775/jquery-iframe-hide-show)